# Does blobstore URL expire? Getting 500 error

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I've got a fairly new site where I upload images using the blobstore
and storing the url in my datastore model as an db.StringProperty().

When the file is uploaded I get the serving url with: `image.imageUrl = images.get_serving_url(str(upload_files[0].key()))` where image is my datastore model.
I haven't modified the code for about 2 weeks and it's been working so far.

But all of the sudden all url's just returns 500 error when trying to open them.

The URL http://lh4.ggpht.com/JfA6nTibsx99EJ2TQoQZr5OVXhQUj_tJK0wCP3FJSRq9RhCzUFLAwsR1q0bzplmqRaRu6fTnNPqDFzpxzMMBeva9FJ9WRXdAqgA
just returns 500 error.

Some what strange is that adding a resizing (adding =s720) param works:

http://lh4.ggpht.com/JfA6nTibsx99EJ2TQoQZr5OVXhQUj_tJK0wCP3FJSRq9RhCzUFLAwsR1q0bzplmqRaRu6fTnNPqDFzpxzMMBeva9FJ9WRXdAqgA=s720

Anyone encountered this? Sounds strange the a url would expire.

..fredrik

**EDIT:**

Reading the documentation I interpret that it should always be the same URL (am I wrong?):

*The URL returned by this method is always public, but not guessable; private URLs are not currently supported. If you wish to stop serving the URL, delete the underlying blob key. This takes up to 24 hours to take effect.*

Comment: Nothing, no error's. But that kinda makes sense since the images them self is not hosted on my application.

Comment: I don't think that you need to call str(key) you can pass only the key.

Comment: Check the blobstore that the key is still there

Comment: I checked the blob view and all images are there. But there key doesn't match any part of the serving_url stored on upload. Do one need to store the key and then get a serving url for each request?

Comment: You *don't* need to store the key, the key is only a pointer to the blob store. you might want to store the key in order to the delete the blob.

Comment: Thanks, but that should mean that my solution should work. Only other reason I could think of is that for some odd reason the serving_urls have changed and the =s720 version are cached. Due to a new deploy of my application? A new deploy mening a different key-path?

Comment: Both image links display properly on my browser.

Comment: i have exactly the same problem. The links work in some locations, and don't work in others. Although they work when I resize them to 200. Did you manage to get this working somehow or it did just fix by itself? How did you fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the same issue as 3789:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3789

Try appending =s1600.

1600 is the maximum size the high-performance can serve.  Appending 1600 should get the native size, or 1600 -- which ever is smaller.

Comment: Seems to be. I had the problem yesterday. But today it works fine! I'll append =s1600 as a safety measure.